# Electric potential difference

Tags: electrostatics

If the electric charge is zero, does it mean the potential will always remain constant. Can you prove it mathematically? I would appreciate

Comment: It will be $net charge?$...So why would work be done(potential) to bring a test charge from infinity ?

Comment: If the charge is zero, then there is no electric potential...

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a conductor it'll be constant inside the body and There'll be presence of charges on surface not inside Because electric field is always perpendicular to conductor and electric potential means potential to bring a charge from a certain point to a given point hence there's no charge inside the surface and We know that :- 
[image]